# How prove $ \frac{2}{\sqrt3}F \geq s-1 $ for convex quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry, inequality, geometric-inequalities

Let $Q$ be any convex quadrilateral of area $F$ and semiperimeter $s$.

Suppose that length of any diagonal of $Q$  $ \geq$ length of any side of $Q$  $\geq 1$

How prove $ \frac{2}{\sqrt3}F \geq s-1 $?

Comment: What is the "semiperimeter"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiperimeter

Comment: Why to compare area units with lenght units? Do we need to take the inequality as only involving real numbers despite of their dimension?

Comment: @Cragfelt Could it be that $2/\sqrt{3}$ means twice the area $F$ divided by the length of $\sqrt{3}$? This segment of length $\sqrt{3}$ can be the hypotenuse of a right triangle with legs of unity and $\sqrt{2}$, the latter of which is the diagonal of a unit square. I'm just winging it ... $\frac{2F}{ \sqrt{3} }$ could also be $F$ divided by the leg of a "$\frac{\pi}3$ right triangle".